# Check If Site URL is SharePoint Site or Team Channel Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, graph-api, microsoft

Is it possible to check if a site URL belongs to a SharePoint site or Teams channel site using Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect if a SharePoint site is part of a Team channel of not, you can use the [Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint of **Graph API**:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D30')`

The `Root Web Template` property will give you values like 'TEAMCHANNEL#0', 'TEAMCHANNEL#1' for Team channels (or STS#0, STS#1, SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0 for regular SharePoint sites).

An alternative is to use **SharePoint REST API** and check the value of `WebTemplate`:

`https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-sites/_api/web`

Comment: What's the expected value for the WebTemplate? I tried to check its value for both "Team Channel Site" and a normal created site and it showed "GROUP" for both. I believe this might not be a clear indicator here

Comment: `Team Channel Site` is for private channels, as private channels, due to specific permission, have their own SharePoint site. For regular channel, there is no dedicated site, so `Group` will be the value of the template.

Comment: I see. I believe with this we still have limitation to see if the site is a true SharePoint site or a teams site

Comment: In fact you can get every group connected to MS Teams https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams#request, and get SharePoint site connected to a Team https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#access-a-group-team-site